# How to avoid script execution if disabled option is clicked?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've got a problem with FF and select elements - regard the following snippet:

```js
function fct() {
 alert("Hello World");
}
```

```html
<select size="5" onclick="fct();">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" disabled>Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

If I use Chrome (60.0.3112.78) and try to click on the disabled option then no alert will be shown (as I aspected). But if I do so in FF (55.0.2) then the alert will be shown.

What can I do to receive the same result in FF as in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `onchange` instead as this won't be triggered when clicking a disabled element. As someone mentioned before in a comment, you still select the select element, so basically Firefox's behaviour is still correct.

```js
function fct() {
 alert("Hello World");
}
```

```html
<select size="5" onchange="fct();">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" disabled>Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!